# Extracting public keys from windows keystore

Tags: java, xml, encryption, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to sign a file with private key
using windows keystore. I also wish to enclose the public key (.cer x509) of the signing digital signature. The .cer file is currently exported from windows certificate collection manually and saved to .cer file but I wish to generate the .cer at the time of signing. Below is the code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
            String alias = "";            
            ks.load(null, null) ;
            alias = ks.aliases().nextElement(); // read the first element only
            Key key;
            key = ks.getKey(alias,null);
            Certificate certificate = ks.getCertificate(alias);
            RSAPublicKey pub = (RSAPublicKey) certificate.getPublicKey();
```

Here how do I write the variable pub into .cer file to be enclosed with signed file for verification at recipient side.

Comment: What is your question? What is not going as you have expected or what errors do you get?

Comment: Just got the solution: I was writing the RSAPublickKey from pub variable to .cer file, whereas I should be writing Certificate to file, which worked for me and it shows valid .cer file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the solution: I was writing the RSAPublickKey from pub variable to .cer file, whereas I should be writing Certificate to file, which worked for me and it shows valid .cer file. Thanks.